# # Docusign:javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Method not implemented

Tags: docusignapi

I am facing below error message while calling login method using credential API. I've crosschecked login credentials and it look's fine to me.

Error Trace:

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Method not implemented.  
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Method not implemented.| 
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:156)| 
at $Proxy432.login(Unknown
```

I am using CXF 2.6.1 as a web service container.
One more Info: With Jboss and LJS I am able to make the call but when deployed in NW I am getting above exception.

Login method implementation:

```
Login login = new Login();
    login.setEmail("[" + INTEGRATOR_KEY + "]" + creds.get(IntegratedSystemTypeEnum.USER_EMAIL_PROP));
    login.setPassword(creds.get(IntegratedSystemTypeEnum.PASSWORD_PROP));
    login.setReturnBaseUrl(true);
    LoginResponse loginRes = credApi.login(login);
```

Looking forward for your suggestions.

Comment: Can you post what is getting passed to DocuSign? And what SOAP endpoint you're using?

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for responding. I am using below end point URL:         https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/credential.asmx                                      It's test system so can't provide you payload. But I must tell you that I am using the same code base with identical docusign credential in my local machine running on jBoss and it's working fine there. Test system is running on Netweaver app server, Could you please tell me what exactly "method not implemented" means here? or what might have lead to this.  Please let me know if you need anything further.

Comment: Additional Info: I am using Docusign Dev myaccount credentials and we are done with the Docusign certification process 1 month back.